# JS Get base64 string multiple files

Tags: javascript

How to get base64 string multiple files in the input type file? I have to send data to external soap api by post method. Faced an understanding of how input multiple works correctly.

```
<input type="file" id="CVFile" name="CVFile[]" multiple onChange="getBase64();" accept="application/pdf">
```

I check the console, when I select several files, I get the result of the first element `.files [0]`, how can I get for each base64 file and collect it into one array?

```
var newFiles = [];

function getBase64() {
    var file = document.querySelector('#files > input[type="file"]').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        // console.log(reader.result);
        newFiles.push(reader.result);
    };
    reader.onerror = function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ', error);
    };
}

console.log(newFiles);
```

When I select multiple files the array is added as one. ***type multiple - is this how it should work?*** If I send this data to the server, can I get two files separately on the server?

Comment: What do you get when you do `.files[1]`? Additionally, try setting 'multiple' attribute on file input https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

Comment: @gp. When I do `.files [1] `- for each item I get empty, and when I select multiple files I get base64